# Why is the input of the following program is as described: Pointers, extern values

Tags: c, pointers, extern

```
int x=0;
int*a=&x;

void foo(int * a) {
    static x=0;
    x++;
    printf("x's value %d ", x);
    *a+=x;
    a=&x;
    *a=x+10;
}

int main(void) {
    foo(a);
    printf("a's value %d\n ", *a);
    foo(a);
    printf("a's value %d ", *a);

    return 1;

}
```

I'm trying to analyze the above. First iteration of foo, when the function reaches to `a=&x`, the a after the function stops to get affected by what happens, since at the end of the function the pointer would go back to the original value he pointed to, now 1. the static x is now 1 as well. Second iteration: How's x got the value 12?! the static `x` became 2, and so I expected 3 to be the value of a.

The output is:

```
 x's value 1 a's value 1
 x's value 12 a's value 13
```

Comment: You can step through your code line-by-line in a debugger, and observe how each line changes the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=&x;
*a=x+10;
```

The above code adds 10 to `x`, because you set `a` to be a pointer to `x`, and then set the value pointed to by `a` to `x+10`.

Answer (score 3):

The line `a=&x` makes `a` point to the static function-local variable `x` (since it's the innermost in scope).  Thus `*a=x+10` in the next line is equivalent to `x=x+10`, and `x` is 11 as we exit the function.  At the next call, we increment `x` by 1, and it becomes 12.